# With multiple AAMs, how to redirect to preferred SSL (UAG) mapping?

Tags: alternate-access-mapping, redirect, url-rewriting

Initially, our SPF server was an intranet-only appliance.
We had a couple of Alternate Access Mappings:

- http:/ /intranet/
- http:/ /intranet.mycompany.local/

We really encouraged the first one - as it was super easy for users to simply type "intranet" in their browser. Then, we decided some folks from our law firm should have access to a special SharePoint calendar that our internal top brass like to use a lot. So, we set up a Unified Access Gateway and added a 3rd mapping:

- https:/ /intranet.mycompany.com/

Now, there have been occasions where Mr. Internal here at mycompany wants to send Mr. External a link to a document. The simple 'intranet' server name mapping may work just fine for Mr. Internal, but, as you guessed, totally fails once Mr. External tries to click on the link to said document from his mail box.

We are hoping to figure out a method:

1. That will allow the first mapping to auto-redirect to the 3rd mapping (UAG)
2. Thus, will permit the first AAM to continue to exist
3. Thus, keep us from having to tell users to change a behavior we previously encouraged

I've noted that Microsoft offers a URL-rewrite add-on for IIS, and I've seen posts elsewhere on stackexchange that were wary of employing such tactics. I think it would be okay in this scenario, as I need more of a redirect than a re-write.

**FWIW**

I realize a redirect isn't going to fix improper links that were previously sent to external users.. but, it should help on a go forward, once an internal user has punched up a sharepoint resource that he wants to share out, he should already have a UAG-ready URL to copy/paste out of the address bar, etc.

Comment: I had to throw in the extra space between the fwd slashes to make stackexchange stop complaining about my URLs.. a little annoying formatting gripe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**URL Rewrite Settings for SharePoint**

Ok, the network admin and myself dove into the *IIS rewrite add-on* and figured this all out in an hour or so.. seems to be working very well for us. Internal users can continue to type 'intranet' into the address bar, and they get redirected to our preferred 'UAG-friendly' alternate access mapping of sharepoint. Sweet!

**Purpose:**

Force people to use Internet accessible URLs so Intranet pages are available wherever.

**Getting Started...**

Clicking 'Add Rule..' will give you a wizard to create a new IIS ReWrite rule. In the initial wizard screen, scroll to the bottom of the different template icons and choose 'CanonicalHostName' and hit Next. It will then prompt you for the desired host name you prefer users to be directed to.. just type it in. e.g. "intranet.mycompanydomain.com". See the following screens for how we configured it after that...

[image: URL Rewrite Settings for SharePoint]
**Synopsis**

We setup two conditions, which quickly read as follows:

1. your host name doesn't match up with the pattern we would prefer
2. OR, maybe you got the right host name, but you came via http

THEN

- Redirect to the secure version of the URL and tack on whatever path and query string info that was originally requested

In addition to the IIS re-write settings, company computers must have https://intranet.mycompanydomain.com listed as a local intranet site.

[image: Intenet Options - Intranet Zone Security Settings]

This will keep them from getting prompted for network credentials, when accessing the site in-house and getting redirected to a fully-qualified domain URI.

Comment: POSSIBLE PITFALLS WE ARE WORKING THROUGH A WEEK LATER:
1.) Oulook calendar connectivity (redirects confuse it)
2.) Custom app connectivity (copier designed to interface w/SharePoint must be configured to go to preferred URL)